# Fetching mysql data is not working in laravel after importing CSV file manually

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, phpmyadmin

I have a model TestDirectory in laravel and test-directory table in mysql. After i manually importing a CSV file in to the mysql table via phpmyadmin, calling TestDirectory::all() is not fetching any data. But previously it was working fine.

Any direction please.

Comment: Can you please try with a query builder query  and update your question with result, that will give better idea on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your model:

```
protected $table = 'your_table';
```

Comment: I have already provided that.

Comment: The problem comes after i manually importing the CSV file in to phpmyadmin just laravel model refuses to fetch the table data.  i have around 1600 rows on the table.

Comment: Can you share screenshots and code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

You should try fillable property on model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'colume_name',
    'colume_name2'
];
```